# Live accessibility Checker

Tags: javascript, html, testing, accessibility, wcag

I am wondering if anyone knows of any program / tool / or addon that offers a feature like the Live Accessibility Checker in Microsoft Office Word for html coding.

I think it would be great to be able to offer our developers something like this that flags accessibility errors as they are coding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools for checking conformance with Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) of published websites such as WAVE and Total Validator.  A full list is maintained on the W3 website: http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete

However it doesn't appear there are any for checking within an IDE as you're coding, which is what you're looking for.  The nearest would be if you're developing something like PHP / classic ASP where changes can be  constantly published to a test website and a check subsequently performed with one of these external tools.

In general currently I think that's the best option to consider, including into any build scripts a call to an external tool for WCAG check and potentially parsing the output for number of non-compliances.  It doesn't meet the 'live' check, but probably about the next best.

EDIT - one possible tool that may fit the bill (for users of Eclipse IDEs) : http://www.eclipse.org/actf/

> The ACTF componentry and the utilities
>   will be integrated into a single
>   tooling environment on top of the
>   Eclipse framework. The framework
>   components will function cooperatively
>   with each other and with other Eclipse
>   projects to provide a comprehensive
>   development environment for creating
>   accessible applications and content.

Comment: @Community Any way someone can give Kris the 50 rep I had offered as a bounty? I did not get to check for the answer until today.

Comment: no worries if not - I've got 25 for the upvote and accepted.  Also it's piqued my interest, so think I'll be checking back on this to see if tooling improves over time - something of a hot topic for my development team trying to reduce the number of accessibility issues as easily as possible

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with any IDE that has had an on the fly accessibility checker while you code, but I use http://wave.webaim.org/ sometimes.

Comment: Yes WAVE is great.  It is also available as a plug in, so you can do your tests from the webpage with one click.  Thank you for your reply.